# How to access external resource (JSON DATA) via $resource in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm trying to retrieve weather data from openweathermap.org (JSON) ,

this is my service code:

```
weatherApp.service('forecastService', [ '$resource', '$sce', function 
 ($resource, $sce) {

    this.getWeather = function (city, numDays){

        var key = 'b3cc85931eae059522f3a9b8c5260f6e';

        var link = function() {
           return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/");
        };

        var weatherAPI = $resource(link(), { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});

        var weatherResult = weatherAPI.get({ q: city, cnt: numDays, appid: key });

        return weatherResult;
    };

}]);
```

this is my controller code:

```
weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope', '$log', 'forecastService', function($scope, $log, forecastService) {

    $log.info(forecastService.getWeather('Davao City', '5'));

}]);
```

[Kept on getting this error, please help T_T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Oyfd.png)

```
angular.min.js:123 TypeError: c.split is not a function
    at C.setUrlParams (http://127.0.0.1:50003/core-js/angular-resource.min.js:12:269)
    at Function.l.(anonymous function) [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:50003/core-js/angular-resource.min.js:10:156)
    at Object.getWeather (http://127.0.0.1:50003/project-js/forecast.factory.js:14:40)
    at new <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:50003/project-js/forecast.controller.js:3:31)
    at Object.instantiate (http://127.0.0.1:50003/core-js/angular.min.js:44:272)
    at http://127.0.0.1:50003/core-js/angular.min.js:94:141
    at Object.link (http://127.0.0.1:50003/core-js/angular-route.min.js:7:322)
    at http://127.0.0.1:50003/core-js/angular.min.js:17:3
    at ra (http://127.0.0.1:50003/core-js/angular.min.js:85:35)
    at n (http://127.0.0.1:50003/core-js/angular.min.js:70:226) "<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">"
```

Comment: Hide your secret

Comment: I can just  disable or create a new key anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is too late, but I just had the same question as you did and solved.

I think the issue comes from using trustAsResourceUrl, it passes the url as undefined when angular tries to split it, it gives an error.

I just added the openweathermap domain to the whitelist and then create the resource without trustAsResourceUrl:

```
weatherApp.config(function($sceDelegateProvider){
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
   // Allow same origin resource loads.
   'self',
   // Allow loading from openweathermap
   'http://api.openweathermap.org/**']);
});
```

And then create the resource:

```
$scope.weatherAPI = $resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast", {get: {method: "JSONP"}});
```

Notice that I removed the { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, it was causing another error.

Regards.